# File move doesn't work

Tags: php, directory, copy, unlink

It's supposed to move the file to a new directory, but it's not working. It worked on my old hosting site, but not any more:

```
<?php

if (isset($_post['submit']))
{

$myVariable = $_POST['pdf'];
$pdf = $myVariable;
$users = '/Users/';
$proc = '/processed/';
$sourc = '/uploaded/';


}

$host = "";
$user3 = "";
$db_name= "";
$pass= "";

$con = mysql_connect($host, $user3, $pass);

if (!$con) 
{ 
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); 
} 
mysql_select_db("db490855420", $con);
$agent=($_POST['agentname']);
$desc=($_POST['desc']);
$date=($_POST['date']);
$pdf=($_POST['pdf']);

$sql = "INSERT INTO `db490855420`.`documets` (`agentname`, `description`, `date`, `filename`, `numb`) VALUES ('$agent', '$desc', '$date', '$pdf', '1');";

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con)) {
die('Error: ' . mysql_error()); 
} 

mysql_close($con);



$origsource = ($users.$_SESSION['username'].$sourc.$pdf);
$newsource = ($users.$_SESSION['username'].$proc.$pdf);
$srcfile= ($users.$_SESSION['username'].$sourc.$pdf);
$dstfile= ($users.$_SESSION['username'].$proc.$pdf);
copy($srcfile, $dstfile);
unlink($srcfile);


?>
```

posts to the database just fine but its just not moving it to the new folder. and yes the paths exist

Comment: Do you have any errors in your PHP logs?

Comment: could you remove the not-relevant parts? if deleting is the problem, why do you post us database code?

Comment: this is all the code that is executed when the user hits submit. i was wondering if it could be a placement issue

Answer (score 0):

Check your directory permissions and make sure you have write permissions (755)